# Как убрать такое сообщение?

Tags: forms, php

Всем привет, есть код

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
<input type = "submit" value = "Получить 100500$" name = "send" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["send"])){
mysql_query("UPDATE tb_world SET money = money + 100500$ WHERE username = 'Csharp");
}
?>
```

Так вот, после того как форма отправится, если нажать F5 то появится сообщения, типо отправить форму ещё раз... и если нажать то данные опять прибавятся, это дыра в сайте.... Так вот скажите как убрать такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После отправки формы делать редирект на эту же страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Если все происходит на этой странице, то:

1. Обнулять все введенное в форму
2. Переменную сенд обнулять.